# Avro a replacement for Writables

Tags: serialization, hadoop, avro

I am very new to Hadoop and have to delve into its serialization. I know that Hadoop comes with its own serializer called Writables. I was curious to know whether Avro (or protobuf, thrift) replaces the Writables interface or Avro is just meant for serializing the MR client data but not the internal communication between say namenode and datanode.

Answer (score 0):

AVRO is a serialization library (with apis for a number of languages). AVRO is an alternative to using/implementing your Key / Value objects as Writables, but hadoop still uses it's own RPC data structures when communicating between the various services (datanodes, namenodes, job and task trackers).

Answer (score 0):

I've read somewhere that Avro may well end up being the standard internal data exchange mechanism/serialization framework within Hadoop, which makes sense as it is based on inheritance, much like the "new" Hadoop API (the one that uses the mapreduce namespace for its libraries), whereas the "old" API (mapred libraries) is based on interfaces. That means, in practice, that you can certainly use avro with both APIs, although one or two things may require custom code if you're using the mapred libs (e.g. multiple output formats, chain mappers).

But Avro offers far more than "just" doing away with the need for your own writables (although that is, in my view, a considerable plus): it offers fairly efficient serialization, the choice between serializing against generated entity classes (like thrift requires) or using a so-called GenericRecord structure instead, and not having to have tagged data. This is possible as Avro always has its data schema available at read and write time (it's actually saved in json format as a header in the data file) which means you have the option of "projecting" from one set of fields to a subset of those fields by simply providing this information implicitly in the schema used to read the data. You can then adapt to changes in input data structure by tweaking your schemas, rather than changing your code in multiple places. You can also change the way your data is sorted by defining your schema appropriately (as there is an optional ORDER attribute avalailable).

Comment: But what about this - http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ProtocolBuffers. It says that from hadoop-0.23 onwards the native binaries are required to compile this and later versions of Hadoop. Is it that Apache is pushing for protobuf instead of AVRO as the internal serialization framework?